# why doesn't cfcookie allow setting domain= to a subdomain for CFID/CFTOKEN?

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, cfcookie

```
<cfcookie name="CFID" value="#session.cfid#" domain=".demo.labs.dev">
```

yields:

> Set-Cookie: CFID=4215; **Domain=.labs.dev;** Expires=Sat, 04-Jul-2043
>   01:43:49 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly

But if I use `<cfheader>` directly:

```
<cfheader name="Set-Cookie"
      value="CFID=4212; Domain=.demo.labs.dev; Expires=Sat, 04-Jul-2043 01:37:03 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly">
```

yields:

> Set-Cookie: CFID=4212; **Domain=.demo.labs.dev;** Expires=Sat,
>   04-Jul-2043 01:37:03 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly

And that's really what I want.

Why does `<cfcookie>` behave this way?  Current workaround would be using `<cfheader>` instead.

Comment: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3593673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is now fixed...

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3593673

Answer (score 1):

Have you reproduced this error with a leading `.` in the domain value? According to [CF8](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_c_12.html), [CF9](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5f.html) and [CF10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5f.html) docs, the domain attribute value `Must start with a period.`.

Comment: The spec said client should treat it as having leading `.`